# How to translate "then" for an event in the past?

Tags: traducción, pretérito, tiempo

As an example of a simple question and answer about an event in the past:

> ¿Quién se casó en julio?
>
> Ella se casó en julio.

In English I could use a placeholder for July and could answer the question as:

> She got married **then**

I want translate this to Spanish but I am not sure how to do this.  The use of "entonces" as a literal translation of "then" seems wrong to me.

How should my English statement be translated?

---

As an analogy, consider:

> ¿Ya comiste en ese restaurante?
>
> Sí, comí allá.

I am looking for a time-based equivalent of "allá".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case of that question

> ¿Quien se casó en julio?

you could respond both using

> Ella se casó en ese mes.

or

> Ella se casó *entonces*.

Either way would work fine for not repeating the name of the month .

You mentioned being unsure about the word **entonces**,  please be certain that it does act as a time adverb [see reference](https://es.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/entonces), to indicate that the action occurred **then**, at that time.

Comment: You're correct that I don't want to repeat July.  But I think I am looking for something like a direct object replacement pro-noun, but for time